# How to download a image from ftp when a image name is unknown ,in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ftp

I am working on downloading a image from ftp ,where my ftp contains multiple images with different names generated every time in a folder.I just need to download a image whose name contains thumbs.jpg in it.
For ex i have 4 images with names

```
2342345232thumbs.jpg 
453455345334snap.jpg,
4534532356pic.jpg,
1240897387trim.jpg
```

from which i want to download a image name which contains **thumbs.jpg**.

how can i achieve this .please suggest

Comment: you can use the [`CFFTPStream` class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFFTPStreamRef/Reference/reference.html) to get the content of the remote directory and the lookup for the image name you are interest.

Comment: how can i get the image name for downloading as the names will be changing.The only fixed thing in the name is thumbs .Thats y i wanted to download a image name containing thumbs.

Comment: in the `ListController` class of the [SimpleFTPSample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243) you can find how to retrieve the name of the files in a remote directory into an `NSArray`, after that all you have to do is use the answer given by [@kevin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643800/how-to-download-a-image-from-ftp-when-a-image-name-is-unknown-in-ios/13644071#13644071) to find the *real* name of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you get the contents of the directory or atleast can retrieve the filenames, you could try string matching using `NSRange range = [imageName rangeOfString:@"thumbs.jpg"]; if (range.location != NSNotFound) // found match` and then download that particular image.HTH.

Comment: :the problem is to get the contents of the directory.How can we do that?

Comment: @tkanzakic has mentioned how you can do that, you could probably just get the names of all files of the directory or maintain a list that updates with filenames each time a file is added and just download that file and check for your required image name in it.

Comment: :Ya i understood how to do it,but my listcontroller class is returning stream open error everytime .What might be the problem,can u  suggets me

Comment: It would help if you posted more code to tell us what you've done so far.